# SSRS Switch text box

Tags: reporting-services, switch-statement, iif

I have a requirement where I have a document called 'F' 'R' and 'C' (@DocNumber)
When I type this into my report, I have three fields that get populated. I want to condense this into 1 text field and create an expression to say

```
Iif document = 'F',
   show Fields!FRSDisplay.Value,
Iif document = 'R',
    show Fields!RSDisplay.Value,
Iif document = 'C',
    show Fields!CSDisplay.Value,
NULL()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `IIF()` you should easily be able to accomplish this. You're basically there.

```
IIF(document = 'F', Fields!FRSDisplay.Value,
    IIF(document = 'R',Fields!RSDisplay.Value,
        IIF(document = 'C',Fields!CSDisplay.Value,NOTHING)))
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to accomplish this would be with the `SWITCH` statement.  Try the following expression:

```
= SWITCH(Parameters!DocNumber.Value = "F", Fields!FRSDisplay.Value,
         Parameters!DocNumber.Value = "R", Fields!RSDisplay.Value,
         Parameters!DocNumber.Value = "C", Fields!CSDisplay.Value,
         true, "")
```

This will cycle through the conditional statements and display the correct field as required. The final `true` will capture any `DocNumber` value that does not match and set the field to nothing.